# How to prevent Google Maps API v3 from caching tiles (to save storage space)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, caching, google-maps-api-3

I have a strange issue regarding caching of the Maps js API for which I couldn't find any solution.

My situation is as follows:
We want to display a simple website including a map based on Maps API v3.
The website shall be displayed on an embedded device which uses a modified WebKit engine.
Therefor displaying and using Google Maps works great.

But here comes the problem:
Our embedded device has only few storage space (maybe a few 100 KBs).
The Maps API caches every map tile (which usually makes sense!!!), so after the user is moving around the map for some time, we get an error that the cache is full.

Is there any possibility to tell the Maps API not to cache the tiles, to only cache a specific number of tiles, or even to remove the cached tiles programatically by ourselves?

I couldn't find any approach or solution regarding this issue, so it would be really great if somebody has an idea.

Thank you in advance
Markus